# JMX. Is it possible to make nested MBeans?

Tags: java, jmx

For example, I have some storage which I want to manage via jmx. I want to have control over all members of storage together and separately. Interface of storage may look like this:

```
public interface StorageMBean {
    int getSize();

    int disableAll();

    // ??????
    List<EntryMBean> getAllEntries();
}
```

And interface of single storage entry like this:

```
public interface EntryMBean {
    String getName();

    void disable();
}
```

So I want to be able to run jconsole and disable all entries at once or one by one. Now I see only one way: register some GroupStorageMBean where I put group methods. And register many individual EntryMBeans. And now I need to keep all this objects in sync. It would be easier if I could register StorageMBean and it would provide nested MBeans as attribute or something like this. So via such method I would be able to obtain all entries and work with them individually. I hope my explanation was not very confusing. Is it possible to do such thing?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a `void disableByIndex(int i)` or a `void disableByName(String name)` method that can disable an individual instance may work for you. I'm not sure that creating nested MBeans can be possible, but anyway I think it's a unnecessarily complex solution, and almost sure JConsole cannot deal with them.

Hope this helps.